# Is 6% CPU & >180 MB RAM usage normal for exim4 on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, exim, cpu-usage, memory-usage, debian-buster

I just (attempted to) set up `exim4` on Debian 10. Is the above normal for `exim4` running under root when I run `sudo systemctl restart exim4.service`? Seems a bit high for an MTA.

I have `root: MyUsername` set in `/etc/aliases`, changed `lsearch{/etc/email-addresses}` to `wildsearch{/etc/email-addresses}` in `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`, and set `root: myemailaddress@gmail.com` & `*:    myemailaddress@gmail.com` in `/etc/email-addresses`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you measuring?

Comment: In KSysGuard & `glances`